# R - make geom_line dotted/dashed/sold by category

Tags: r, ggplot2

my df looks like something like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 cat          eff   count   segment   segment2
    1              1            0     123     plane    plane_0
    2              2           25      12     plane   plane_25
    3              3           50      54     plane   plane_50
    4              4           75      34     plane   plane_75
    5              1           50      62       car     car_50
    6              2           75      12       car     car_75
    7              1           50      11      boat    boat_50
    8              2           75      10      boat    boat_75
", header=TRUE)
```

I need it to put this dataframe to line graph. I crated this code, but I need to divide this by color and line color.

Plane should be red, car should be green boat blue. If eff is 0 then line should be solid, if eff is 25 then line should be dashed, 50 = dotted, 75 twodash.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(cat), y = eff, color = segment2)) +
  geom_line(stat = "identity", size = 1.5, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point(size = 3.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = as.numeric(cat), y = eff)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(eff)), size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = segment), size = 3.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("boat" = "blue", "car" = "green", "plane" = "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("0" = "solid", "25" = "dashed", 
                                   "50" = "dotted", "75" = "twodash"))
```

[image: plot]

(Note: based on the sample data, the points corresponding to car are completely hidden beneath other points.)

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I think that ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(cat), y = eff, color = segment2)) is necessary. I mean that segment2 othwervise plot seems to be not ok

Comment: Do you mean you wish to map colour to a variable with 8 different values, but only have 3 different colour values that you want to use?

Comment: I need separate line for each row from df. Thats why i use color = segment2. But at next step i need to create color by segment column and line type by column eff.

Comment: Doesn't each row correspond to one point? A line / segment requires at least a starting & ending position. It would be clearer if you include a sketch in your question of what your ideal output looks like.